# ResultSet#next() is returning false even though my query is correct

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, resultset

I have written the following code in an jsp file.. basically what it dose is that it checks whether there is any data with the particular bank name, card number and password..to check this i have used a select query.. the query is correct but the result set is returning false.. i have even checked the query separately.. its working fine.. is there any problem with this code?? please help.. I'm using netbeans as my IDE and Derby database..

```
    String URL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Bank Database";
    try{
        Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,"Bank","Bank");
        String qry="SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE BANK='"+bname+"' AND CARD_NO='"+cname+"' AND PASWORD='"+pswrd+"'";
        Statement sq=cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=sq.executeQuery(qry);
        if(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString("PASWORD").equals(pswrd))
            {
                cn.close();
                out.println("<script>function redirect(){ window.location=\"scsfl.html\";} setTimeout('redirect()',3000);</script>");  //redirects to another page   
            }
        }
        else{
            cn.close();
            out.println("<script>function redirect(){ window.location=\"failed.html\";} setTimeout('redirect()',3000);</script>");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){ System.out.print(e);}
```

Comment: Since this is JSP, I'm not sure where `System.out` is going, but did you check the server logs?

Comment: ya.. there is no error in that..

Comment: And how do you know that the statement is correct?

Comment: i have executed select statement separately.. and also i checked the values of bname cname and pswrd.. they were also correct..

Comment: You should meet [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: You're doing this wrong anyway. You should be using a `PreparedStatement`, and the SQL query already checks the password, so you don't need to do that yourself: all you care about is whether there was a result.

Comment: But it's hard to believe. Have you really spelt `PASWORD` correctly? Both times? If so, why is the column name misspelt in the database? And are you sure what's really happening? There are three possibilities, not two: (a) `ResultSet.next()` returns false; (b) comparing the passwords returns false; or (c) `ResultSet.next()` returns true and comparing the passwords also succeeds. Your code doesn't log all three possibliities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments your actual code shows many problems:

1. You are using a `Statement` instead of a `PreparedStatement` which is more secure and can prevent some Hackers move like SQL Injection, you can find more information in [**JDBC Statement vs PreparedStatement – SQL Injection Example**](http://www.journaldev.com/2489/jdbc-statement-vs-preparedstatement-sql-injection-example).
2. You are checking the password in your Java code while it's already done in your SQL query, so the query checks if the password is correct it will return a result otherwise the result will be empty.
3. Closing the connexion in the `if..else` statement is a very *bad* practice, you better use a `try..catch` statement to deal with it in `finally` block where you will close respectively the `resultset`, the `prepared statement` and the `connexion`.

I tried to improve your code and this's what you should do:

```
    Connection con = null;
    String URL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Bank Database";
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String qry="SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE BANK=? AND CARD_NO=? AND PASWORD=?";
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,"Bank","Bank");
        ps = con.prepareStatement(qry);

        //set the parameter
        ps.setString(1, bname);
        ps.setString(2, cname);
        ps.setString(3, pswrd);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            out.println("<script>function redirect(){ window.location=\"scsfl.html\";} setTimeout('redirect()',3000);</script>");  //redirects to another page 
        } else {
            out.println("<script>function redirect(){ window.location=\"failed.html\";} setTimeout('redirect()',3000);</script>");
        }
    } finally {
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close();
        ps.close();
        con.close();
    }
```

Comment: VG but it should be `if (rs.next())` as in the OP's code. There really aren't going to be multiple users with the same username and password, and even if there are it isn't correct to send the same piece of HTML twice. And you 've omitted the failure case provided by the OP.

Comment: @EJP nice point , yes you are right about it I'm changing it.

Comment: You changed half of it ;-)

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your improvment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are in a correct database, I made this mistake few times.
Query correct, wrong database.

Answer (score -1):

In general, closing the Connection should automatically close any Statements and ResultSets associated with that Connection.

In this code, i have closed the connection interface reference inside rs.next() method. That's the reason JSP Engine cannot convert it to java file. Its showing error message. Please find the both code and Corresponding Error message.

Jsp code:

```html
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "test", "test");
   
   String username = "Anil3";
   String password = "123";
  
  
   PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from User_Login where userID='"+ username +"'");
   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
 while(rs.next())
 {
   if (password.equals(rs.getString("password"))) 
    {
   con.close();
  out.print("inside if loop");
    }
   
   else{
    
    con.close();
    out.print("Inside else loop");
   }
 }
```

Error Message:

```html
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /test.jsp at line 28

25:   
26:    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from User_Login where userID='"+ username +"'");
27:    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
28:  while(rs.next())
29:  {
30:    if (password.equals(rs.getString("password"))) 
31:     {


Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection: next
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
 org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:124)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


root cause 

java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection: next
 oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:181)
 org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:97)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

You shouldn't close connection inside ResultSet. please remove the con.close() statements inside your code and try it. It will work.

Comment: Why whould you check the password in the Java code while SQL is doing it for you.

Comment: He isn't using `while (rs.next()`: he is using `if (rs.next())`. He isn't getting `java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection: next`, at least so far as we know. None of this is 'the reason JSP Engine cannot convert it to java file', because it *does* both 'convert it' *and* execute it, according to the OP. Arbitrarily rewriting the question to suit a preconceived answer doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: @chsdk, I am not retrieving password in my query.I am retrieving only user  name after that i checked with password in my java code.

Comment: Yes I know, that's what I intended to say, why whould you check for the `name` in the query and retrieve the results then check for the `password` in the Java code while you can simply retrieve the wanted result in the query and check for both values.

Comment: @AnilReddy You don't appear to understand your own code. Your SQL query already contains a match on `PASWORD`. It is therefore 100% redundant to check it again. You won't get any rows where it doesn't match. All you're accomplishing is another possible site for an error. It is pointless.